# Xml and Xna saving and loading multiple levels windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm trying to create a game save system which involves saving a score for each level when each level is complete and was thinking of using xml. I'm quite confused about how to do this. I've seen serialization like the particle system example on MSDN, but each particle system is split into seperate files. I want something like this:

```
parent

  level
    id 1 /id
  score 0 /score
  /level
  level
    id 2 /id
  score 0 /score
  /level
```

etc. And then all the data is loaded from one xml. What then confuses me as well is how I would serialize and unserialize it. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you give more detail to your problem? Do you have problems with saving and loading, or with the generation of the XML Document?

Comment: I'm just sort of stuck with so many options. I'm struggling with how you would deserialize and serialize the data or even if I should serialize at all? I have a class which has two arrays which I want to store all the levels ids and scores in. I want to be able to load the information in and then save the information out again when a level is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup a single class that contains all the data, such as:

```
public class SavedGame
{
    public class Level
    {
        public int id;
        public int score;
    }

    [XmlElement()]
    public List<Level> level = new List<Level>();
}
```

Then you can serialize and deserialize it using the `XmlSerializer` class.  I'm sure you can find many many examples of that if you searched the web.

Comment: Ok yes, I've got the class already, but does that mean I have to split each level into a seperate xml? The only reason I want the scores is for my level select screen so I can tell what levels the user has played.

Comment: No, you can serialize the entire `SavedGame` object to a single xml file.